# log version of boost binomial_coefficient?

Tags: c++, boost, binomial-coefficients

Fairly simple question but I've been having trouble finding anything online.

I'm looking for a log version of `boost::math::binomial_coefficient`, which can handle some of the larger values generated by my code.

In R there is `lchoose` which provides this, however I can't seem to find the equivalent in c++

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to calculate it yourself.  However [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64716/400273) asks how to do that, and it turns out not to be too bad.  A first approximation is:

```
n log n − m log m − (n−m) log (n−m)
```

A better approximation can be obtained by using another term of the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for log(n!)

```
n log n − m log m − (n−m) log (n−m) + ½(log n − log m − log(n−m) − log 2π)
```

With all of these you are subtracting two terms which are potentially of similar size, so you are vulnerable to loss of accuracy.